# JQuery auto complete not working

Tags: magento-1.8, jquery, autocomplete

I have some js that does an autocomplete:

```
jQuery("#city").autocomplete({
    source: "/route/to/countroller",
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        if((typeof ui.item.province !== 'undefined')){
            jQuery("#city").val(ui.item.city);
            jQuery("#region_id").val(ui.item.province);
        }
        else{
            alert("Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
    }
});
```

I know the the controller gets hit, because i've debugged all of it and up until the point where i return results, everything works as it should work.

When I return the results, I do it like this:

```
return Mage::helper('customerdetails_addressvalidation/autocomplete')->jsonEncode($suggestions);
```

However, the suggestion dropdown under the input never appears to give me the options returned by the controller.

I know that the code works because I previously had the autocomplete JS source option pointing to a file in my magento root (for testing), and the suggestions were returned without a problem.

Is there some trick/special way to return the suggestions from a controller, as opposed to a file in the route?

Comment: Can you see the JSON that is returned by the controller in your browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that instead of returning the suggestion like this:

```
return Mage::helper('customerdetails_addressvalidation/autocomplete')->jsonEncode($suggestions);
```

I had to echo it back like this:

```
echo Mage::helper('customerdetails_addressvalidation/autocomplete')->jsonEncode($suggestions);
```